# JavaScript Protractor While loop never ending

Tags: javascript, protractor

I'm writing JavaScript tests with Protractor

Recently I got an error:

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

But it surely isn't a memory error, I found out something's wrong with that function:

```
ProfilePage.prototype.removeProgrammingLanguages = function () {
    i=0;
    while (i < 3) {
        browser.findElement(By.css("//div/span")).then(null, function (err) {
            if (err.name == "NoSuchElementError") {
                i=11;
            }
        this.programmingLanguagesRemoveButton.click();
        i++;
        });
    }
};
```

I want protractor to click a button until find  element returns a NoSuchElementError (remove all elements from a list).

What's wrong?

Comment: because it is an infinite loop, is that click code actually firing inside the while loop and running or is the while loop locking it up.

Comment: I can't figure it out, I get a JavaScript heap out of memory error and nothing else in log

Comment: What is this function supposed to do? Let's say the above works, what if the button is not clickable? We would find the button and click the button but if it does not navigate to the next page, then it will keep looping until you get an out of heap error.

Comment: First be aware that you are using promises. You first need to resolve them before you can use a loop. This loop will never work.

Comment: I've changed the function using a promise (check above) but it still fails with the same error, the find element and click functions are working correctly outside the while loop, It's strange because protractor isn't even navigating to the destination page, it crashes while page code checking, so the loop doesn't even actually start, how to use while loop  in protractor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to do this

```
ProfilePage.prototype.removeProgrammingLanguages = function removeProgrLanguages() {
    browser.findElement(By.xpath("//div/span")).then(function (err) {
        element(By.css("div.lang-cloud.remove > span")).click().then(removeProgrLanguages);
    }, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err.name);
        } else {
                promise.rejected();
        }
    })
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This loop fires promises as fast as your cpu can create them. You are not making the loop wait for the promise to resolve. So it creates one then moves to the next line of code. Which is a new loop to create one. It will have created thousands of promises before the first one resolves.

You can use [Promise.resolve()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve) to wait for a promise to be resolved.

however you could also solve this by recursively chaining promises like so:

```
ProfilePage.prototype.removeProgrammingLanguages = function removeProgrammingLanguages() {
    return browser.findElement(By.xpath("//div/span")).then(function() {
        this.programmingLanguagesRemoveBttn = element(By.css("div.lang-cloud.remove > span"));
        return this.programmingLanguagesRemoveBttn.click().then(removeProgrammingLanguages)
    })
};
```

This function will stop when a promise is rejected. You will have to change the 'this' reference, because they go funny inside promises.

Comment: thanks, but there are some minor bugs i cant resolve, can you look at this?: http://i.imgur.com/0oWAq1h.png And how would it look like with Promise.resolve() ?

Comment: sorry, should be function() not ()=> for js

Comment: this.programmingLanguagesRemoveButton.click() is throwing Failed: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined, outside the function its working fine, do you know what could cause this?

Comment: this points to the function now. so yo will have to store this.programmingLanguagesRemoveButton in a variable that is reachable inside the function. or give it as a parameter.

Comment: sorry, it's the findElement function thats crashing, Failed: No element found using locator: By(xpath, //div/span). Weird because in sleenium server console i can see 14:28:36.902 INFO - Executing: [find elements: By.xpath: //div/span])
14:28:36.913 INFO - Done: [find elements: By.xpath: //div/span] and outside the function it's working

Comment: the example uses By.css ("//div/span"). that is not correct then

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147737/discussion-between-barteld-and-jedrek-cienicki).